Scalable Database Design
I am creating a website, and this is the database I have designed. I have created this design in such a way that it scales well in the long term. The following features are supported by my database:

Users can create stories.
Users can bookmark (save) their favorite stories.
Users can select a list of stories to create storybooks.
Users can delete stories.
Users can edit stories.
Users can favorite their preferred theme rooms.
Users can like and dislike other users' stories.
Users can comment on stories

I haven't decided the database for my design but I am considering MongoDB and PostgreSQL at the moment. Which database will be most fit for my design?

I have posted my database design in the image. I was wondering if the design is sufficient and scalable. If there are any improvements, please let me know.

As far as I can see, yours is a classic relational OLTP (transactional) model, in which the design of the entities and the relationships plays a primary role in performance and scalability. (Do yourself a favor: add reference integrity constraints, aka foreign keys, where they apply.)
Anyway, and generally speaking, scalability also depends on the data volume and the operations that will be performed on the data. Will you have hundreds of records? Or thousands? Or millions? In which tables? Are you going to generate reports on historic data? Etc.
Please, have in mind that mongoDB and PostgresSQL are two completely different beasts. If you want a classic and solid relational database, with SQL access and complex features, go for PostgresSQL. The choice also depends on your skills and the tools you feel comfortable with.

For now, I have decided to go with MongoDB since I am more familiar with it. I will migrate to PostgreSQL in the future. As far as the amount of data is concerned, there might me a lot of data and I might need historic data too. Most my data is interconnected, meaning I would have to go through the entire collection / table to render a component. I will have many reads than write in my use case.

As I said, your experience and confidence is important when choosing the tools. Just remember that easy at first may be hard at last. MongoDB needs much more "conventional" programming than a SQL database, and is much less performant for certain things. For instance, compare the work you have to do for joining two or more tables, with a couple of conditions. And then compare the performance.

And about your last statement ("go through the entire collection / table"), you DON'T do that with a relational database. You use SQL for asking the server for a specific set of records (which may be actual records or aggregations, from one or more joined tables), and just process this already prepared data in the client. If you do it "manually" on the client, your system WON'T be scalable.
